# Encrypt URL Issue in OKHttp

Tags: android, json, getjson, okhttp

Here Issue is I have to pass the parameter in the URL API but issue is json works in Postman-->Body-->raw

by passing parameters:

```
{"from":"abc","to":"pqr","amount":"10000"}
```

result is:

```
{ 
"errFlag": "0",
"errMsg": "Success",
"result": "1745738346.397"
}
```

But same thing we pass in **OkHttp** we get the other result
here is my code Okhttp:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("from", "abc")
                        .add("to", "pqr")
                        .add("amount", "10000")
                        .build();


                try {
                    post(Baseurl, formBody, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            Log.e("JSONDemo", "IOException", e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            String res = response.body().string();

                            Log.e("res", " " + res);


                            try {

                                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(res);
                                String errFlag=jsonObject.getString("errFlag");
                                if(errFlag.equals("0")){
                                    String a=jsonObject.getString("result");
                                    Log.e("hello........",a);
                                }else{
                                    Log.e("Error", "Wrong");
                                }
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // you can access all the UI componenet


                                    }
                                });


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("JSONDemo", "onResponse", e);
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("JSONDemo", "Post Exception", e);
                }


            }
        }
    });
 private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Call post(String url, RequestBody formBody, Callback callback) throws IOException {

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}
```

Output is:

```
 {"errNum":"404","errFlag":"1","errMsg":"Some fields are missing"}
```

I just want **errFlag=0** then pass the result else not.
Appreciate for help

Comment: Instead of FormBody Why dont you try FormEncodingBuilder

Comment: FormBody is the object of RequestBody.I am not getting FormEncodingBuilder

Comment: Let me post the code how I did it You can try that

Comment: Will be more grateful for that thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        formBody.add("version", version);
        formBody.add("device_id", device_id);
        formBody.add("platform", "android");
        RequestBody body = formBody.build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();    
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                result = response.toString();
            } else {

            }
            result = response.body().string();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Try with this code if it helps you then I ll give you one generic class for this.

Comment: Your are using 'RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()' where as in my case formbody is object of 'FormEncodingBuilder formBody;'

Comment: Mam how will I get FormBody actually i had use same json in every program but this tym something new and challenging question was there.So here FormEncoding is not found I mean it is not coming

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
 add this dependency you will get it

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows,

```
String postBodyParamsJson = "{\"from\":\"abc\",\"to\":\"pqr\",\"amount\":\"10000\"}";
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, postBodyParamsJson);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

Comment: Here not resolved in from,abc,to all keys and parameter.

Comment: @Abhi may be you are accessing on server in wrong way. In my case it's working well. Also check my edit on answer